# HL7Sdk how to add 'PIVL_PPD_TS' and TS in entry.AsSubstanceAdministration.EffectiveTime entry.AsSubstanceAdministration.EffectiveTime

Tags: c#, hl7-cda

Hi everyone,
            I am using HL7Sdk codeplex and  trying to add 'PIVL_PPD_TS' type in entry.AsSubstanceAdministration.EffectiveTime but it generates compile time error . and same problem is with TS type too.  I am able to add PIVL_TS and EIVL_TS without any problem.

```
var p = new PIVL_PPD_TS();
            p.InstitutionSpecified = false;
            p.Operator = new SetOperator();
            p.Operator.HasFlag(SetOperator.A);
            p.Period.Init(5);
            p.Period.Unit = "h";
            p.StandardDeviation.Init(1);
            p.StandardDeviation.Unit = "h";

            entry.AsSubstanceAdministration.EffectiveTime.Add(p);
```

the last line compile time error is "cannot convert from 'HL7SDK.Cda.PIVL_PPD_TS' to 'HL7SDK.Cda.ISXCM_TS'"

The same issue is with TS type . Please guide how to resolve this .

Comment: what is the data type of `entry`?

Comment: entry type is IEntry which is interface type . Below line I m using to create its object and holding it in IEntry interface type     IEntry entry = section.Section.Entry.Append()